# Winter Bash Rep Hunter hat not delivering

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

I was checking my answers and I counted that I have ten answers with positive score, but I wonder why I am not getting the [Rep Hunter](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/rep-hunter) hat? Isn't the trigger to have 10 answers all upvoted in one day?

Here is the image I took 12 hours ago:

[image]

As you can see there are exactly 10 answers that were upvoted in that day, and I counted that all the answers were in the specific day...

Is this supposed to be like this or what?

Comment: Those four/eleven hours didn't set you back one day on UTC, did they?

Comment: @Ollie Nope no.

Comment: Are any downvoted, zero score or deleted?

Comment: @Catija One was downvoted but it had 3 or 4 upvotes, so still positive score...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319556/python-slicing-twice-in-string/65319621#65319621

Comment: @Catija Oh yeah I forgot!!!

Comment: @Catija So you can't have downvoted posts?

Comment: I'd need Yaakov to confirm but I think so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure all your answers on that day need to have a positive score, or else you must have exactly 10:

1. the hat description explicitly mentions this ('**all answers** must have a positive score')
2. I scienced it here on Meta. I had twelve answers for a while, but two with zero score. The Rep Hunter hat didn't appear until I (temporarily) deleted the two answers with zero score.

We'll need Yaakov to confirm whether this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or not.

Comment: Yaakov did indeed confirm [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56535003#56535003) that *all* posts must be positively scored regardless of whether they are accepted or not.

Comment: @Nick thanks for replying but it does not exclude accepted answers, which signifies a more than positive response, and it also awards the author 15 rep. You found the solution because you asked on chat, not on this page. Zero score post = 0 Accepted post = 15

Comment: @Mari-LouA score refers *only* to up and down votes, *not* reputation.

Comment: @Nick I see.  I guess rules are rules, no escaping from that but... still, an accepted answer is a "score" of some sorts. If an OP forgets to upvote or doesn't have enough rep and instead accepts an answer, why shouldn't it count?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree with you, but unfortunately the way it's set up is not to allow that to count. I'll remember it for next year...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Catija to show me that I had one downvoted answer that I deleted, which was this one:

[image: Oof]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319556/python-slicing-twice-in-string/65319621#65319621) is the link.

Gonna work on getting this hat now!