# Hats left floating when viewing "less" information in review queue

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash

I was reviewing a question in the Reopen queue on Stackoverflow where someone who had edited the post had a hat on their profile picture:

[image]

At the time I had the "(more)" dialog open:

[image]

When I clicked `(less)` to hide the dialog, the hat of the user who edited the post remained where it was (as well as being redrawn in the new position):

[image]

I'm using Firefox 83.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: This also happens if there is an answer, the answer's poster is wearing a hat, and you add a comment to the question (or another answer) above it. The hat stays where it was but also moves down with the image. (In case this is browser specific, this is using Firefox 83.0 on Windows.)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm probably the same bug... thanks for pointing out I'd left off the browser info, I've added it now.

Comment: This random floating hat is something I have noticed too. I usually see two floating hats. One near the answers section as @Nick shows and another in the left side margin. They are both identical hats, I often cannot tell which user's though.

Comment: I thought you last question was not a duplicate for the reasons you stated and I voted to keep it open. Why did you delete it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA because the answer given to the proposed duplicate was actually correct, I posted a comment on the answer instead https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358119/winter-bash-rep-hunter-hat-not-delivering/358141#comment1197540_358141