# Visual bug when flagging comments

Tags: bug, comment-flags, mobile-safari

I was flagging some "no longer needed" comments on [a migrated question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/297295/9161) and in some circumstances which I haven't been able to narrow down an extraneous red flag was showing on a comment further down my screen in addition to showing correctly on the comment I was flagging. It wasn't the one right after the comment I was flagging.

I'm browsing in Safari 14.1/iOS 14.7 on my phone using the responsive full site view. Reloading the page fixes the display of the flagged comments. I had the comment list expanded. I was able to reproduce it a few times, but I'm not sure which steps would cause it to happen every time (and I've run out of comments to flag legitimately).

I'm having trouble reproducing this while paying attention to what I'm doing, so I think it's likely that it's something related to me shifting things around or selecting things while dragging the flag dialog around at some arbitrary zoom level.

I caught it happening as I was flagging [the second comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/297655/decad-on-vs-decad-of#comment554435_297655) as "no longer needed". You can see the light blue square around the flag that I had selected. I did not flag the third comment. I did flag too fast and had to dismiss the warning (I have to do that almost every time I'm flagging comments as "no longer needed", so it could be a factor). Refreshing the page makes the flag go back to unhighlighted.

> [image: Screenshot showing three flagged comments when it should be two]

(And there's nothing wrong with these flagged comments; the author updated their question, so they served their purpose.)

Previously, there was a comment that didn't have the flag highlighted between the comment I was flagging and the erroneously highlighted one, so I have a feeling this has to do with the positioning of the comment on the visible portion of the page, not its order in the list.

Comment: I can't get it to happen in my Safari 14.1 on iOS 14.7... can you see what version you are using? you might need to use a site like [whatismybrowser.com](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/)

Comment: This sort of thing has happened a few times in the past several months, but the only other instance I can find is the one [about ghosted hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358247/282094) - there's a few more where there's a *ghost* (duplicate) of an element, a fixed distance from the original; somewhere.

Comment: Do you need to submit the actual flag to see this happen, or does opening the flag modal suffice?

Comment: @Luuklag You have to submit the flag--I'm about 83.2% sure. I noticed the extra red icon twice after I submitted the flag, but the dialog obscures the page on my phone. I've tried moving the dialog to see if I can get it to happen without submitting, but haven't been able to reproduce it.

Comment: I noticed this when closing posts (iOS chrome). You can tap elsewhere on the page to remove the erroneous highlight, iirc.

Comment: @Laurel Would you explain a bit more how closing a post highlighted a comment flag? You were outside of the review queue? Did you vote to close, or flag the question?

Comment: Voted to close from the post. This happened a few times since about last month. I don’t remember what I closed as but here’s a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bq8Q.jpg

Comment: @Laurel Hmm so maybe there's something about the dialogs overlaying the flag. I'll have to pay attention to where the option I'm clicking in the dialog is positioned. Maybe the click is falling through somehow? Web stuff is way outside my wheelhouse. I don't know how web folks accomplish anything without FPGAs.