# Why does long tapping a link appear to upvote the question?

Tags: bug, design, voting, ios

On [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/338406/41273) (please don't cast test votes on it), I used a long tap (approximately where the red is) to see where the link led. However, it caused the upvote button to become highlighted, as if I upvoted (but without changing the score):

[image: tapping link in first line of question]

This happens every time, after I dismiss the popup that comes up due to the long tap in the specified area. I think this highlight is supposed to indicate a hover state, but I have no mouse.

Browser: Chrome on iOS

Possibly related: [Visual bug when flagging comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369630/323179)

Comment: The button redesign brought with it an annoying behavior where touch screen devices will leave the voting buttons highlighted via the `OnMouseOver` event. Unless you "already know" the difference between highlighted & selected voting arrows, this is really confusing. It's made me vote, thinking I am retracting a vote, when I'm really voting.  The `OnMouseOver` button doesn't change the color of the triangle, but voting does. It's an annoying usability issue that hopefully gets addressed, since it impacts new/less experienced users more than seasoned users who eventually get used to it.

Comment: @AMtwo A few days after this was released, I spent a good minute and a half upvoting/unupvoting the same spam trying to get my vote removed :/